# What should I be able to see from the graph of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, waves, wavefunction

I know that the square of the wave function can tell me the most probable location of the particle, but let's say I didn't square the function and I'm only looking at a graph of the wave function itself. What should I be able to tell from its graph?

My question was inspired by these graphs from *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by Griffiths:

[image]

Comment: How are you going to graph the complex number?

Comment: @zeldredge see edited answer. I can kinda see what you're implying but then how do you explain these graphs by D.J. Griffiths?

Comment: How wiggly it is tells you how kinetic-energy-y it is, for instance. In technical terms, the kinetic energy is the con abut of the graph, and faster wiggles generally implies larger concavities.

Comment: @march what is "con abut"?

Comment: That was supposed to say "concavity". Autocorrect.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the square of the wave function can tell me the most probable location of the particle

The term 'location' is somewhat problematic here.

For particle in a 1D well with a *normalised wave function* $\psi$, the Born interpretation tells us:

$$P[x_1,x_2]=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\psi^*\psi dx$$

Or if $\psi$ is Real, then $\psi^*=\psi$, so:

$$P[x_1,x_2]=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\psi^2 dx$$

Schematically:

[image: Born interpretation]

This gives us the probability of finding the particle on the interval $[x_1,x_2]$. Note that when the interval goes to $0$ (because $x_1=x_2$) then $P=0$.

The probability of finding the particle in a *point location* is therefore **always zero** and this is in agreement with *Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle*.  $\psi^*\psi$ is therefore better referred to as the *probability density function*, rather than the misleading probability. **We can only calculate a probability over a specific area of space, not in a point location**.

The wave function $\psi$ shows that it changes signs at the nodes (roots, i.e. zero points). This finds important applications in chemistry because atomic wave functions (atomic orbitals) can only *interact additively*, thereby forming molecular wave functions (molecular orbitals or bonds), if they are of the same sign.

Comment: *The probability of finding the particle in a point location is therefore always zero* - am I correct in thinking that it actually makes sense intuitively that we can't find a particle in a point location because if we imagine a physical wave as the correct representation of the particle, then simply pointing to *one point* on the wave is meaningless - we must talk about ***the entire wave*** in order to talk about where it is.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less correct. More accurately is to invoke the Uncertainty Principle: we cannot know position and momentum *both* with arbitrary precision: $\sigma_x \times \sigma_p \geq \hbar/2$. Set $\sigma_x=0$ and the principle is violated.